# Is there any meaning in having your paper published in the first page (p.1) of a conference proceeding?

Tags: publications, conference, proceedings

I am new to the Academia and unsure if there is any extra meaning in having your paper published on the first page of a conference proceeding. Are the final order of papers just randomly sorted out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might possibly have some meaning for some conferences, but not all, and maybe not many. In fact, many (most?) conferences are organized into tracks and the proceedings likewise.

In CS, I've never given a thought to the meaning of paper order in any conference, worldwide over a career. But fields differ in their general practice.

A very specialized conference would probably use its own concept of ordering, and it might involve perceived interest or quality. But you'd have to ask the committee.

I doubt, however, whether a formal randomization is used.

---

And if order is important, is being the author of the *last* paper something of a downer?

Comment: Indeed. By definition, some paper will be first and some paper will be last.

Comment: @JonCuster, I suppose we could publish on a Möbius band an avoid the issue altogether.

Comment: @Buffy, I thank you for your time in answering the question. The reason I will hold a few days before finally accepting it is because I was hoping to get an insight from someone who deals in organizing such conferences. In the absence of such, I'll make sure to return here. I also had a small giggle from your Möbius strip remark, here.